# Docker is running properly but is not accessible with browser on 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel-based application and I created a docker-compose file using laravel/sail:

```yaml
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

I'm trying to connect the app container using browser.  Since `$APP_PORT` has seted on `8000`, I expect to see laravel first page in hopefully http://0.0.0.0:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000, but I give:

> This site can’t be reached

in Chrome, same thing in Firefox.

Here's the result of `docker container ls`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
663fc79a5338   sail-8.2/app             "start-container"        23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes             0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp, :::5173->5173/tcp, 8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp   app_name-app-1
7311792e085f   mysql/mysql-server:8.0   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp                                   app_name-mysql-1
```

I ran Docker before and for example `0.0.0.0:8088` works properly in another project (which not using laravel-sail).

It's also notable that I checked Stackoverflow and docker community and none of them could solve my problem, my guess is.

It might be related to ssl/tls related issues maybe(?)

Note:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Docker version: 20.10.17

I tried a different port (8088), and it wasn't helpful.

I served Laravel using `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0` and it works fine.

I tried `curl 0.0.0.0:80` in the app container and it works fine (Laravel home page).

I tried `curl 0.0.0.0:80` in my machine (out of Docker) and it gave me:

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I also checked my chrome proxy setting and it seems fine (Disabled).

I disabled my firewall (ufw disable) and nothing changed.

**Update**

app docker logs:

```bash
 sudo docker logs app_name-app-1
```

```
usermod: UID '0' already exists
2024-01-05 22:33:56,718 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
2024-01-05 22:33:56,722 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2024-01-05 22:33:57,727 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 10
[Fri Jan  5 22:33:58 2024] PHP 8.2.10 Development Server (http://localhost:80) started
2024-01-05 22:33:59,005 INFO success: php entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2024-01-05 22:43:16,632 INFO reaped unknown pid 27 (terminated by SIGKILL)
2024-01-05 22:43:16,633 INFO reaped unknown pid 26 (terminated by SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Can you try `localhost:80` or `127.0.0.1:80` instead?

Comment: @Turing85 same error(This site can’t be reached)

Comment: Can you `curl localhost:80` from within the `app` container?

Comment: @Turing85 It works fine and i can see result withing the app container

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a real IP, you should not use that in your browser.  Use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` on the host the container is running.  Your `docker container ls` output shows that you've mapped host port 8000 to container port 80, so you should be trying `http://localhost:8000` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in your browser.

Comment: @Don'tPanic   I tried localhost:8000 and 127.0.0.1:8000, and both of them resulted in the same error. (This site can’t be reached), while I can reach the site when i serve Laravel using the php artisan command

Comment: OK so first step of debugging, check the logs - have you looked at `docker logs app_name-app-1`?  It is maybe nothing but `8000/tcp,` in the `docker container ls` output looks strange to me, any idea where that comes from?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  I guess 8000 is coming from '${APP_PORT:-80}:80', APP_PORT seted on 8000 in .env. And I also updated the question so the result of (docker logs)   have been added.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the actual build context look like in `./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2`? Because I'm only seeing two running containers, and the logs seem to suggest that your Laravel container is just a PHP FPM process. Without a Reverse Proxy like NGINX or Caddy, you won't be able to access it directly unless you're using PHP's built-in development webserver.

Comment: No, I mean the `8000/tcp,` listed by iteself under ports.  `0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp` are expected, the IPv4 and v6 mappings, but there is also `8000/tcp,` with no mapping, I don't know what that is or why it shows up.  Maybe not relevant.  `ghestika-app-1` is not the name of the container listed in your `docker container ls`, is it really the right one?  One other idea - you mentioned you tried `php artisan serve`, did you shut down that server before trying docker?

Comment: @maiorano84  I'm not sure about this, but there is a supervisord.conf which contains a command(php artisan serve) and it uses PHP build-in development webserver.  supervisord.conf  is calling in start-container

Comment: @Don'tPanic ghestika-app-1 is the real name of the application and i changed it to app_name, however in my update i forgot. the real name is ghestika. sorry about that. and yes i shut down (php artisan serve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key message in your log is `PHP 8.2.10 Development Server (http://localhost:80) started` that shows that your app is binding to localhost.

That means that it'll only accept connections from localhost. In a container, localhost is the container itself. So it won't accept connections from outside the container.

You need to have it bind to `0.0.0.0` to get it to accept connections from outside the container. You haven't shown your Dockerfile, so I can't see what command you use to start your app. In your post, you mention adding the option `--host=0.0.0.0` to your `php serve` command and it's something like that you need to do.

Comment: My problem solved. Thanks. https://github.com/laravel/sail/tree/1.x/runtimes/8.2 (dockerfile and supervised). After I tried to test your answer my problem solved but as you see the host is already set to 0.0.0.0, I'm not sure how it solved but I'm trying to figure it out and post an answer.